# Upgrading Beanstalk Corretto 8 Tomcat 8.5 to Corretto 17 Java SE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, corretto

Currently, there is no Beanstalk platform configuration with Tomcat and Corretto 17 (There is only Corretto 8 with Tomcat 8.5 or Corretto 11 with Tomcat 8.5).

My goal is to find if there is a way to migrate my Java application from Corretto 8 (with Tomcat) to Corretto 17 (Java SE) and still be able to use my current Tomcat configuration, without having to reconfigure the whole application server configuration.